# Add values to input - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

On my website, I have a list of tickets. In top of that list, I have this checkbox, that can check ALL checkboxes in the list:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall"  class="checkall" name="checkall">
```

This checkbox, checks all other checkboxes with the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkall').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})


$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $("#userInfo").toggle(!($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0));  
});

$('#close').click(function() {
    $("#userInfo").hide();
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');  
});
```

**Although**, I also wish to have all the selected checkbox values put into my form. I use this code for that:

```
function updateTextArea() 
    {
         var allVals = [];
         $('#c_b :checked').each(function(){
           allVals.push($(this).val());
         });
         jQuery('#ticketIds').val(allVals);  
    }
    $(function() 
    {
          $('#c_b input').click(updateTextArea);
          updateTextArea();
    });
```

And here is my form:

```
<form method="post" name="edit">  
   <input type="hidden" id="ticketIds" name="ticketIds" value="">       
   <input type="submit" class="button gray" value="Okay, do it" name=""> <a href="#" id="close">Close</a></form>
```

My problem is, whenever I use the "check all" checkbox, NO values is added to the #ticketIds. ONLY when I check each checkbox myself, the values are added.

How can I do, so it works both ways?

Comment: Fyi, you can use `.prop('checked', val)` with `val` being a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling your function whenever you click the check/uncheck all checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkall').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
        updateTextArea();
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');   
        updateTextArea();     
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but this might help:

```
$('#checkall').toggle(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    $('input:checkbox').trigger('click'); // add this line
    $(this).val('uncheck all')
},function(){
//...
```

Comment: Very bad... `updateTextArea()` is being called once for every checkbox on the page. It only needs to be called once.